# adding and subtracting for BODMAS system

Tags: java, math, arraylist

I have been building a simple formula calculator and have gotten stuck with addition and subtraction. As you should know, when calculating an equation, you follow the arithmetic rules of precedence, i.e. brackets, order: *power functions, division, multiplication, addition and subtraction*. The problem is that addition and subtraction are given equal priority, so therefore you can read it from left to right. Here is my code so far:

```
{
ArrayList<String> equation = java.util.Arrays.asList({"2","-","2","+","5"});

  while(equation.contains("+")){
          addMe(equation);
  }
  while(equation.contains("-")){
          minusMe(equation);            
  }
}

public static void addMe(ArrayList<String> numberList){
 for (int i = 0, n = numberList.size(); i < n; i++) { 
   String value = (String) numberList.get(i); 
   if(value.equals("+")){

    String wordBefore = (String) numberList.get(i-1);
    String wordAfter = (String) numberList.get(i+1);
    System.out.println("This is the word before " + wordBefore);
    System.out.println("This is the word after " + wordAfter);
    double doubleFromBefore = Double.parseDouble(wordBefore);
    double doubleFromAfter = Double.parseDouble(wordAfter);
    double answer = doubleFromBefore + doubleFromAfter;
    System.out.println("This is the answer: " + answer);
    String stringAnswer = String.valueOf(answer);
    String newNum2 = value.replace(value, stringAnswer);
    numberList.set(i,newNum2);
    numberList.remove(i-1);
    numberList.remove(i);
    break;
  }
 }   
}
```

The minusMe method is exactly the same as the addMe method except with "-" in relevant places. The problem I am having is getting the equation read from left to right one item at a time and either doing the add or subtract method. Ideally I think I need to combine my 2 while loops with an iterator, to solve the problem but my attempts haven't worked. Any idea as to if this will solve my problem? If so please provide amended loop.

Regards

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have a look at this

```
java.uti.ArrayList<String> equation = java.util.Arrays.asList({"2","-","2","+","5"});
java.util.Iterator<String> equIterator = equation.iterator();
int result = 0;
int multiplier = 1;
while(equIterator.hasNext()){
     String operandOrOperator = equIterator.next();
     if(operandOrOperator.equals("+")){
          multiplier=1;
     }else if(operandOrOperator.equals("-")){
          multiplier=-1;
     }else if(operandOrOperator.equals("*")){
          result*=Integer.parseInt(equIterator.next()); // Assuming that next element will be there always after operator.
     }else{
          result+=(multiplier * Integer.parseInt(operandOrOperator));
     }
}
System.out.println("Final result : " + result);
```

Comment: Works, but how would I do a multiplication in this manner? If it is a lot of work, don't bother, as this works with my code so far. Just waiting for a reply on another question, to see if this will also work with that.

Comment: This doesn't handle division, modulus, or exponentiation at all, and it doesn't implement operator precedence correctly either. Consider for example 1+2*3. Downvote.

Comment: @EJP I did not provided complete answer. I just tried to suggest a method to do the arithmetic operations.

Answer (score 0):

You are doing this all wrong. You need to use at least a recursive-descent expression parser, or Dijkstra's shunting-yard algorithm, maybe even a parser generator if this is going to grow into some kind of a language. You will find all these things via a web search.

Comment: Thanks. Keen to look into it, just need something basic at the moment to enable my program to achieve the desired output. Will do a remodel while it is running