# Math function Power from String ("2 power 3")

Tags: android, string, pow

I have to perform a pow function while getting equation from string like `"2 power 3"`. I know there is function `Math.pow(a, b)` and also I can use `for loop` to achieve this , but the problem is both methods needs integer and I have equation in string. I don't know how to parse this string and separate both variables. And there is another problem. my equation could get little bit complex as well. for instance it could be like `"2+3*5/5 power 2"`

```
public class CalculationActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    EditText editText;
    Button btnCalc;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_calculation);
        editText=findViewById(R.id.et_regular_dep);
        btnCalc=findViewById(R.id.btnCalculate);
        btnCalc.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                String equation= editText.getText().toString();
                CalculateResult(equation);
            }
        });

    }

    private void CalculateResult(String equation) {
        // here to perform power function
    }
}
```

Comment: you can try https://stackoverflow.com/q/25225475/8089770.. with this you can acheive starting numbers/equation before word "power" and after the word "power". and can parse it to int and perform that pow method on that

Comment: [See this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14517390/adding-and-subtracting-for-bodmas-system) I hope this will help you.

Comment: @VishvaDave this gives the number only after the keyword power or any other keyword

Comment: @Syed try my answer and let me know if any issues

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this :

```
 String eq = "2 power 3";
 String no2 = eq.substring(eq.indexOf("power") + 6 , eq.length());
 String no1 = eq.substring(0,eq.indexOf("power")-1);

 Log.d("no1",no1);
 Log.d("no2",no2);
 Log.d("ans",Math.pow(Double.parseDouble(no1),Double.parseDouble(no2))+"");
```

Comment: thank you @Vishva Dave . but it only solves if equation doesn't has other oprands  like String eq= "2+3+5-2 *10 /2 power 3 "

Comment: yes for this formula you need to use other math functions or need to solve it manually i am not getting any exact solution for this

Comment: well thank you @VishvaDave i will look for further answer

Answer (score 0):

another easy way to do it

```
String eq = "2 power 3";
eq = eq.trim(); // if it has extra space at the start or end
String no1 = eq.split(" ")[0];
String no2 = eq.split(" ")[2];

Log.e("no1", no1);
Log.e("no2", no2);
Log.e("ans", Math.pow(Double.parseDouble(no1), Double.parseDouble(no2)) + "");
```

Comment: what will happend if String eq = " 2 power 3";

Comment: you gotta trim your main string first before splitting it. string operations are always tricky